# how to set comment in python zipinfo

Tags: python, zip

I finished the level 6 in [python challenge](http://www.pythonchallenge.com) with library `zipfile` and found that the answer was recorded in `ZipInfo.comment`. I wonder how to put text in this field. I have read the source code for python library `zipfile` but couldn't find any method to achieve it.

Dose anyone know about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write it when you create the `ZipFile` object:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', 'w') as zip:
    zip.write('file.py')
    zip.comment = b'This is my comment'
```

The text has to be entered as binary with prefix `b`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.comment

If your archive already exists, you can also use the mode `a` to append the comment alone:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', 'a') as zip:
    zip.comment = b'This is a new comment'
```

---

To set the comment on file zipped, you have to access the `ZipInfo` object like below, or create it with method [`from_file`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file):

```
with zipfile.ZipFile('myzip.zip', 'w') as zip:
    zip.write('file.py')
    info = zip.getinfo('file.py')
    info.comment = b'zipped file comment'
```

Comment: No, I mean the zipinfo.comment https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.comment

Comment: That's it ! Thanks !!